# Jenkins as Windows Service : How to schedule daily build (something similar like cron job)

Tags: jenkins, build, cron, schedule

We have installed jenkins as windows service and want to schedule daily build for one of my build & deploy task.
I tried with "schedule build" but it does not schedule on daily basis automatically and schedule once only at specific time , I just want to make sure that it does it on daily basis at the same time.
I also installed cron job plugin but looks like that does not work for windows.

Please suggest.

Thanks
XslGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With settings like in the screenshot, the build will run everyday at 8:00AM

[image: jenkins]

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer , when you configure you job there is an option to build periodically , not able to post screen shot though.

I hope it helps.

Thanks
Xslguy